# arduino controlled spark plug with ignition coil

Tags: inductive, spark, powermosfet, arduino-uno

I am trying to built a ignition system which will have the following

- Spark plug
- Ignition coil (I don't know the spec of these. but this one is from Honda Activa)
- Some switching circuit

I found something similar to my requirement when I googled it.
!(https://sites.google.com/a/liljedahl.dk/christian/guides/arduino-spark-plug)

But when I tried this after 6-7 secs the Arduino stops working.

Does anyone knows the cause for this please help me with it.

[image]

Comment: It's would be much easier if you add a schematic.

Comment: what @LongPham asked and post the program listing

Comment: `Does anyone knows the cause for this?` .... only a person that can physically touch the arduino may be able to answer the question ...... you gave almost no information in your description

Comment: @jsotola Um, I do not understand.

Comment: there is no wiring diagram .... there is no program listing .... we have no way to guess what is wrong ..... only a person, that can see your wiring and can see the program that you are using, can answer the question

Comment: @LongPham, please answer this question .... `My automobile is making a strange sound. What is wrong?`

Comment: Poor layout can make high V E fields induced in low voltage wires can damage the gate driver .  Not shown in a flyback diode necessary.

Comment: I'm actually trying something similar, but I'm not using the typical 2 wire coil, i have a 3 wire coil, 1: ground 2: b+ 3: trigger signal, the transistor is built it the coils, now I in this particular car only 2 of the 4 trigger signals work, cyl# 1 and #4, but cyl # 2 and #3 don't ( the pcm doesn't output them it's faulty) so I wanted to use the signal of cyl#1 to trigger #2 & #3 according to their firing order, but I'm not too sharp with coding yet, do you have any coding suggestions or a base i can work on? On my car the firing order is 1234, so 1&4 are good but I need a code that can fill

Answer (score 1):

The design is flawed! It's missing protection!

When you are switching an inductive load you need a protection against the voltage spike produced when the power supply current is suddenly reduced or interrupted.

See protection circuit down to the right.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode

[image]

Comment: Well, mosfets have intrinsic diode.

Comment: And that protect against? See the picture I added to my answer and compare that to the design of the MOSFET.